# Using a user input text string in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, user-input

I have a code that extracts data from a website using specific tags depending on the country entered. However, I want it so that the user inputs a country and then the appropriate details are extracted. The code I have is as follows:

```
library(rvest)

x <- readline(prompt = "Enter Country:   ")

url <- "http://oceantax.co.uk/links/tax-authorities-worldwide.html"
pg <- html(url)

country <- pg %>% html_nodes(xpath="//a[contains(@title, 'x')]")

country <- pg %>% html_nodes("a[title~=x]")

argname <- country %>% html_text()       # get the text of the anchor
argurl <- country %>% html_attr("href") # get the URL of the anchor
y <- rbind(argname,argurl)
```

Which doesn't work since where the x is in the code, it doesn't replace it with the user input. If I manually replace the x with Argentina for example, it works perfectly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that x is treated as a text within quotes. It is read literally as the character "x" and not as a vector.

See my lines creating the "formula" vector below. I use paste() to concatenate a string which feeds into the scraping functions.

This works on my end. Let me know if it works for you.

```
library(rvest)

x <- readline(prompt = "Enter Country:   ")

url <- "http://oceantax.co.uk/links/tax-authorities-worldwide.html"
pg <- html(url)

formula<-paste("//a[contains(@title, '",x,"')]",sep='')
country <- pg %>% html_nodes(xpath=formula)

formula<-paste('a[title~=',x,']',sep='')
country <- pg %>% html_nodes(formula)

argname <- country %>% html_text()       # get the text of the anchor
argurl <- country %>% html_attr("href") # get the URL of the anchor
y <- rbind(argname,argurl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using just package `XML`. Also, this uses `sprintf()` to substitute in the value of `x`.  It's nice when you have multiple values to substitute, and it is often more efficient than `paste()`

```
library(XML)

x <- readline(prompt = "Enter Country:   ")
"Argentina"

url <- "http://oceantax.co.uk/links/tax-authorities-worldwide.html"

node <- htmlParse(url)[sprintf("//a[contains(@title, %s)]", x)][[1]]

do.call("rbind", list(argname = xmlValue(node), 
    argurl = xmlGetAttr(node, "href")))

#         [,1]                                       
# argname "Federal Administration of Public Revenues"
# argurl  "http://www.afip.gob.ar/english/"
```